# What is the implication of "A g-sorted array remains g-sorted even after h-sorting it"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was reading shell-sorting when I came across the above statement. What does this imply and what difference does it make to the way I look at shell sorting?

PS: I am not looking for the proof of the statement.

Comment: Possibly better suited for [cs.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you might imply that the next sorting phases don't "screw up" the previous steps: if you g-sort the array and then perform h-sorting, the resulting array is still g-sorted, so it was "nothing wrong" about applying the h-sorting. And as insertion sort (shellsort is based on it) is quick for almost ordered arrays, you can argue that h-sorting did something positive (if it changed something) and did no harm at not-that big of a cost. So it's always a progress: it was either nearly-linear, or made some progress in sorting.

The question of selecting the step values is a separate and very important issue for shellsort, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

From what I was able to find, I think it means, that if array is Shell sorted with step G, it will remain sorted with step G after sorting with step H. It's important relation between G and H, I guess it is true for H < G, but don't take it for granted.

But it's hard to guess what it might mean, without access to original text.

Comment: For any relation between `g` and `h`.

Comment: The question is - why is this relation important?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, that just means that there is some transformation h so that a list with the g-sorted property is still g-sorted once transformation h is applied to it, making it also h-sorted.

In the context of shell sorting, what I understand by the notion, is that after applying a transformation that makes the list g-sorted, that the sequence of every gth element is in sorted order.  Te statment means that even after applying the h-sort transformation to the list, making it h-sorted, the list still has the g-sorted property.

The important significance of that is that h-sorting the array does not undo previous sorting steps, ensuring that the list will eventually be sorted.

Comment: The 1-sorting ensures that the list will eventually be sorted :)

Comment: @unkulunkulu True. I didn't really think of that at the time.  The basic idea though is that performing a higher-numbered sort transformation can be used as a sort of 'shortcut'.  Having it already 2-sorted means it takes much less to get it 1-sorted, and having it 4-sorted makes it much easier to get it 2-sorted, etc.

Comment: Yeah, agree, also see my answer, it's just an idea I had, not definitive answer, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following array is 5 sorted, if we 7 sort it, The final result is not 5 sorted anymore. So, it think the aforementioned statement is correct if h <= g.

Index: [0 to 29], 30, 35, 40, 42

Value: [...-1..], 10, 15, 20, 0

Answer (score 0):

It simply means, if two elements are sorted on performing g-sort, they will remain sorted even after it is h-sorted for h <= g.